# Large increase in speed by removing object mapping from database call

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

You can see my code at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/da0d2b99e5adf7db5e08

I'm using Entity Framework 6/LINQ with C# in an ASP.NET MVC project. The database is MySQL.

It appears when I split object mapping out of the database calls, it increases speed by more than 2x (4000ms for 1000 iterations vs 1600ms for 1000 iterations). I've tried switching the order and precaching the database calls (I'm not sure if they cache, but I tried), with no change in results. The object lists(returnList1 and returnList2) that the test cases output seem to be the same.

A) Have I messed up my test cases or are these results accurate?
B) If I haven't messed up my test cases, why wouldn't test #1 just compile to code similar to test #2, are there certain benefits of test 1 over test 2?

Comment: try to use glimpse (with plugin for EE) and see what DB queries are issued http://getglimpse.com/

Comment: I'm trying that now @Vitaliy

Comment: @Vitaliy I got glimpse running and it's pretty cool unfortunately it doesn't seem to work properly with my MySql for some reason, I'm getting an error: "Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection'." I'm looking to see if there are other tools that might work now

Comment: Try to use some MySQL profiler to trace queries

Comment: Okay, so I downloaded and installed Jet Profiler, and it only shows one query for all my test cases (though it has some sort of top queries, not all queries results), which made me thinking. I'm guessing that test case 2 is slower because it is trying to run the database call every time, where test case 1 caches it and skips it, and that in actual code without the for loop, the tests would be of equal or near equal speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question because I also asked the question other places, and recieved helpful answers. It is likely due to [Cold vs. Warm Query Execution, as you can see on msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

Also, the comments suggesting using a plugin to watch DB queries were interesting, however simply removing toList from a Linq To Entities query that is formatted the way it was in my question shows the relevant raw mysql query.